# How can I avoid certain lines from .bashrc and .inputrc from being loaded in tmux?

Tags: readline, tmux

I have these lines in my .inputrc:

```
"(": "\C-v()\ei"
"[": "\C-v[]\ei"
"{": "\C-v{}\ei"
"\"": "\C-v\"\C-v\"\ei"
"\'": "\C-v\'\C-v\'\ei"
```

This autocloses quotes and brackets in a terminal. But it causes an inconvenience in a tmux session: when I send text containing quotes to frome one pane (vim) to another pane (bash / python / R etc), every quote is turned into two, very annoying.

Is it possible to disable these lines in (and only in) tmux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tmux sets the TMUX environment variable, so in .bashrc (or .profile or whatever):

```
if [ '' = "$TMUX" ] ; then
  echo not in TMUX
else
  echo in TMUX
fi
```

You can set INPUTRC to override the default .inputrc location, so you could have a tmux one and a non-tmux one, and export a suitable INPUTRC value in .bashrc depending on TMUX. You could even concoct a suitable .inputrc (e.g. in /tmp) for that session based on a "common" file and a "non-tmux session" file.

Unfortunately tmux exports TMUX, and so subshells started from a tmux session will have TMUX set regardless. Not found a way round that yet.

Comment: This is in .bashrc, how can I apply the same idea in .inputrc?

Comment: you don't - you use TMUX-dependent stuff in .bashrc to set INPUTRC to point at an appropriate file (i.e. have a tmux-inputrc and a non-tmux-inputrc, and set (and export) INPUTRC as appropriate depending on whether TMUX is set).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this in ~/.bashrc:

```
if [[ '' = "$TMUX" ]]
then
    set -o vi
    bind -m vi-insert '"(" "\C-v()\ei"'
    bind -m vi-insert '"[" "\C-v[]\ei"'
    bind -m vi-insert '"{" "\C-v{}\ei"'
    bind -m vi-insert '"\"" "\C-v\"\C-v\"\ei"'
    bind -m vi-insert '"\047" "\C-v\047\C-v\047\ei"'
else
    echo Welcome to Tmux!
fi
```

## UPDATE

Adopting user3392484 's suggestion, I found this much better:

```
if [[ '' = "$TMUX" ]]
then
    export INPUTRC=~/.inputrc
else
    export INPUTRC=~/.tmux.inputrc
    echo Welcome to Tmux!
fi
```